# CSVのファイルを比較し、差分データを抽出する方法

Tags: python, csv

やりたいこと： 
下記の2つのcsvファイルを比較して、両ファイル内の差分を抽出し別のファイルにデータを書き込みたいです。

csvデータ①

```
A  B      C  
1 アメリカ   ○
2 カナダ　　×
3 日本     △
4 イタリア　 ○
5 イギリス　 □
6 メキシコ  空白
7　空白　　空白
```

csvデータ②

```
A  B      C  
1 アメリカ   ○
2 カナダ　　□　→”×”→”□”変わった部分ですが、”□”は除外
3 日本     ○ →”△”→”○”変わった部分
4 イタリア　 ○ 
5 イギリス　 ×→”□”→”✖️”変わった部分
6 メキシコ　空白
7　空白　　空白
```

抽出したいデータは”○”と”✖️”で変わった時だけです。
＊ヘッダ付きと改行されている形式で下記のように表示したいです。

```
A  B      C  
3 日本     ○
5 イギリス　 ×
```

こちらのコードを記載しましたが下記のように表示されます。

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')

ret = df2[~df2.A.isin(df1.A)]
ret.to_csv('test3.csv', index=None)

print(ret.to_csv)
```

出力
ヘッダだけしか表示されないです。

```
<bound method NDFrame.to_csv of Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []>
PS C:\Users\test\Documents\test>
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: `df2.iloc[df1.compare(df2).index]`

Comment: @metropolis 
回答ありがとうございます。上記の方法で来ますが、すいませんあとで追記しましたが抽出したいデータは”○”と”✖️”で変わった時だけです。csvデータ②の２行は除外したいです。可能でしょうか。

Comment: 「抽出したいデータは"`○`"と"`✖️`"で変わった時だけ」というのがイマイチ厳密な定義ではないですね。`空白`や`△`を含めた変更前と変更後の全ての組み合わせパターンを表にして、どの場合を抽出したいかを追記してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif  
いつもお世話になっております。今回下記の方法と.str.contains#特定の文字を検索で"○"と"✖️"だけ抽出できました。

Comment: 何らかの処理を積み重ねれば結果は出ますが、それで全ての場合の確認や、あるいは後で少し条件を変えたい時に自分で対処出来ますか？ ということです。それを整理して応用し易いように資料として残しておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: かしこまりました。まだまだ勉強中ですが、色々と試してみます。いつもありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis 
`df2.iloc[df1.compare(df2).index]`以前教えて頂いた方法で上手く差分抽出されておりましたが` Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`のエラーが表示されるようになりました。データをみると特にヘッダーが変わっていないです。ただ2行が追加されております。行が追加されるとどのように差分を抽出すれば良いか。分かりますか。

Comment: `df2.iloc[df1.compare(df2).sort_index(inplace=True)]`
`sort_index(inplace=True`を追加しても同じエラー表示されます。
もし解決策あれば教えていただけます。お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aの値が２つのファイルで一対一に対応している前提で、該当しそうな条件で例として書いてみました。
条件を適宜調整してください。ご参考まで。

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-↲

import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')

# 1.今回×に変わったところ
df2_state = df2['C'].isin(['×'])
# もともと○、□だったところ
df1_state = df1['C'].isin(['○','□'])
# 両方を満たすケース
f1_state= (df1_state & df2_state)


# 2.今回○に変わったところ
df2_state = df2['C'].isin(['○'])
# もともと△、×、□、空白だったところ
df1_state = df1['C'].isin(['△','×','空白','□'])
# 両方を満たすケース
f2_state= (df1_state & df2_state)

# 1.2.それぞれの条件を満たすもの
final_state = ( f1_state | f2_state )

# 最終的にほしいDetaframe
final_answer = df2[final_state]

final_answer.to_csv('test3.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: こちらも回答ありがとうございます。
 上記の方法と.str.contains#特定の文字を検索で"○"と"✖️"だけ抽出できました。